# Using purely Regex Method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a text which contains

```
text = """Dave 2008-09-20 2020-05-31 dave@google.com
Steve 2009-01-23 2020-04-30 steve@gmail.com 
Rob 2007-02-14 2020-04-30 rob@gmail.com 
Ryan 2010-02-11 2020-03-10 ryan@yahoo.com 
"""
```

There are two forms that I need to change it into:
First:

```
['Dave 2008-09-20 2020-05-31 dave@google.com',
 'Steve 2009-01-23 2020-04-30 steve@gmail.com',
 'Rob 2007-02-14 2020-04-30 rob@gmail.com',
 'Ryan 2010-02-11 2020-03-10 ryan@yahoo.com']
```

Second:

```
[('Dave', '2008-09-20', '2020-05-31', 'dave@google.com'),
 ('Steve', '2009-01-23', '2020-04-30', 'steve@gmail.com'),
 ('Rob', '2007-02-14', '2020-04-30', 'rob@gmail.com'),
 ('Ryan', '2010-02-11', '2020-03-10', 'ryan@yahoo.com')]
```

I get all the result:-
but surely it is not purely regex use..

for first: I use

```
splB = re.split(r'\n+',text.strip())
splB
test = [x for x in splB]
test
```

for second I use:

```
splC = [(tuple)(re.split(' ',x.strip())) for x in re.split(r'\n',text.strip())] 
splC
```

Both get same result, but I want to use regex as my means..
If it is possible I don't want to use something like list.split() but regex and regex only..

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to use regex? They can prove to be quite messy when it comes to case coverage unless written with utmost precaution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure regex for the **first form**:

```py
re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]+\s(?:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s){2}\w+@\w+.[a-z]+", text)
```

Result:

```py
['Dave 2008-09-20 2020-05-31 dave@google.com',
 'Steve 2009-01-23 2020-04-30 steve@gmail.com',
 'Rob 2007-02-14 2020-04-30 rob@gmail.com',
 'Ryan 2010-02-11 2020-03-10 ryan@yahoo.com']
```

**Explanation**:

- `[A-Za-z]+`: matches the name, e.g., "Dave".
- `\s`: matches the space between the name and the first date.
- `(?:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s){2}`: non-capturing group that matches exactly two dates (`{2}`) in the form YYYY-MM-DD, followed by a whitespace.
- `\w+@\w+.[a-z]+`: matches the email.

---

For the **second form** you could do something like:

```py
regex = r"[A-Za-z]+\s(?:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s){2}\w+@\w+.[a-z]+"

[tuple(re.split(r"\s", row)) for row in re.findall(regex, text)]
```

but it would be definitely simpler just using the function `str.split`:

```py
[tuple(row.split(' ')) for row in re.findall(regex, text)]
```

In both cases, the result is:

```py
[('Dave', '2008-09-20', '2020-05-31', 'dave@google.com'),
 ('Steve', '2009-01-23', '2020-04-30', 'steve@gmail.com'),
 ('Rob', '2007-02-14', '2020-04-30', 'rob@gmail.com'),
 ('Ryan', '2010-02-11', '2020-03-10', 'ryan@yahoo.com')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, unless this is just for practice, using `regex` is unnecessary here. `str.split` will be more straightforward in this case. If this is just for practicing `regex`, this will work for you:

```
splt = [s.strip() for s in re.split(r"\n(?=\w)", text)] # your "first form"
formatted = [] # your "second form"
for s in splt:
    formatted.append(tuple(re.split(r"\s", s)))
```

If you're looking for a one liner, this is entirely possible:

```
x = [tuple(re.split(r"\s", s.strip())) for s in re.split(r"\n(?=\w)", text)]
```

```
[
    ('Dave', '2008-09-20', '2020-05-31', 'dave@google.com'),
    ('Steve', '2009-01-23', '2020-04-30', 'steve@gmail.com'),
    ('Rob', '2007-02-14', '2020-04-30', 'rob@gmail.com'),
    ('Ryan', '2010-02-11', '2020-03-10', 'ryan@yahoo.com')
]
```

#### Regex Explanation

The first one is straightforward: `r"\s"` simply just splits on each whitespace. This is equivalent to `str.split(" ")`.

The second expression, `r"\n(?=\w)"` uses a positive lookahead to match `\n` which are *only* followed by a characters in the `a-zA-Z0-9_` set.

Comment: Actually this is just an exercise.. Idk if my lecturer wanted one liner or there's actually an expression that will suffice all the criteria.. for now, I will not accept this as an answer.. but just upvote it..

Comment: Sounds good, let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: yeah.. nothing at this moment.. but I learn the positive lookahead match.. which is good..